# How to make a copy on object and not copy its memory address in Java

Tags: java, object, reference, copy, clone

I am trying to make a copy of an ObjectA, which has another ObjectB in it, which also has 6 other ObjectC's, but I dont want to have a copy of ANY of their memory addresses, so if I updated any of the original objects later on, it will not update the copy's values (which consists of all three objects). I have tried implementing the clone() but that still doesnt work for what I am trying to do.

Here is what I am trying to do (yes I know this looks ridiculous...):

```
   void rotateEntireCubeClockwise(){

  System.out.println("Changing view of cube...rotating entire cube clockwise...");
  CubeAlgorithms a2 = clone();
  cube.left = a2.clone().cube.clone().front.clone();
  cube.front = a2.clone().cube.clone().right.clone();
  a2.clone().rotateTopClockwise(1);
  cube.top = a2.clone().cube.clone().top.clone();
  a2.clone().rotateTopCounterClockwise(1);//undo
  a2.clone().rotateLeftClockwise(2);
  cube.back = a2.clone().cube.clone().left.clone();
  a2.clone().rotateLeftCounterClockwise(2);//undo
  a2.clone().rotateBackClockwise(2);
  cube.right = a2.clone().clone().cube.clone().back.clone();
  a2.clone().rotateBackCounterClockwise(2);//undo
  a2.clone().rotateBottomClockwise(1);
  cube.bottom = a2.clone().cube.clone().bottom.clone();
}

public CubeAlgorithms clone() {
    try {
        return (CubeAlgorithms) super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {        
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

CubeAlgorithms contains a Cube object, and the Cube object contains 6 CubeSide objects(front, left, back, right, bottom, and top)

Both Cube and CubeSides also contain a clone method similar to the one you see above.

My problem with this code is that I want it to rotate a cube clockwise, however the only rotation that it does is the very last one.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally called a "deep copy." There's not a single way to do it; all of the classes being deeply copied have to help out in one form or another.

One approach is to have a copy constructor (that is, a constructor `CubeAlgorithms(CubeAlgorithms)`) that does a deep copy on all of the incoming object's fields. Of course, to do a deep copy of those, you need to do something similar to them -- and so on.

Another approach, if your classes are all serializable and performance isn't a huge concern, is to serialize and deserialize your objects. In this, I don't necessarily mean java's built-in serialization: you could use Jackson to JSON-ify them and then read that JSON string back out, etc.

Comment: The first thing that I tried was the copy constructor, actually. However, some of the values where null for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

I think your code looks complex because in that method you are trying to clone the object and modify it (rotate it) at the same time.

Also, you are invoking the "clone" method of all the objects several times, so each time you would be creating a new copy. That could explain why only the last operation is applied.

I'd suggest you separate the operations and first clone the entire cube (with all the sub-objects it has inside) and then once you have the new Cube object, then rotate that one (the original one will not be rotated since the second object is a separate one).

To clone the object, you should write a "clone" method in all the classes. The "clone" method should create a new instance of the class, and then populate the attributes by cloning them as well.

For example, in the "Cube" class:

```java
public Cube clone() {
    Cube newCube = new Cube();
    newCube.front = this.front.clone();
    newCube.back = this.back.clone();
    newCube.left = this.left.clone();
    newCube.right = this.right.clone();
    newCube.top = this.top.clone();
    newCube.bottom = this.bottom.clone();
    return newCube ;
}
```

You should then implement the other classes' "clone" method in a similar fashion (create a new instance, then populate the attributes with clones of the attributes in the "this" instance).

Once you have successfully cloned the object, then do whatever operation you need to rotate it (and you don't need to call "clone" several times, just clone the cube once).

```java
Cube rotateEntireCubeClockwise(Cube originalCube) {
   Cube newCube = originalCube.clone;
   // now manipulate the "newCube" to make sure it rotates
   // ...
   return newCube;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your input but why would I have to create a new copy from scratch? Wouldnt I be loosing all of the current values if I do that, by using the above clone method?

Comment: You won't loose the current values because when making the copy you are assigning the new attributes using clones of the original ones. Take a look at the Cube clone method. The "front" attribute of the new one is initialized using a copy of the original one's "front" attribute.

Comment: I have create completely new objects for all of the values and have copied the old object.value.clones to the new ones, but that still doesnt work. Got any idea why?